# Are configuration questions about Retropie and associated hardware appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about Retropie and configuration of the associated hardware and peripherals appropriate on this Q&A site?

Please note that this is different from the previous questions concerning emulation, as this more focused on configuration of Retropie hardware and not about the games themselves or emulation in general.  Some of the this might cover hardware configuration scripts that are generated for various controllers, or it may include Raspberry Pi accessories such as the Control Block or Power Block that can be used with Retropie.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Retropie is an emulator for Raspberry Pi.  The emulator itself, yeah, that would be something we help with.  The hardware itself, I think would be enough outside our expertise to say it should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: [Are questions about software for gaming hardware on-topic?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/are-questions-about-software-for-gaming-hardware-on-topic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to know how to get Retropie the emulator working, yeah, we'd help support that aspect; emulation itself is on-topic.

That said, questions about the associated hardware are **not**.  How to configure hardware, or if an issue lies in the Raspberry Pi, are not in our expertise. We might be able to help with the gaming specific accessories, if there are controllers or such, but beyond that, the Raspberry Pi isn't a gaming tool; those questions don't belong here.

Comment: You might want to add that the [raspberrypi.se] site can help with the hardware into your answer.